# Google Sheet take a cell by value

Tags: google-sheets

I got a problem:

In cell `C1`, I fill with a formula `=A1+B1`

In cell `D1`, I want to extract the value of `C1`

*But the catch is...*

Whenever `C1` is changing due to changes in `A1` or `B1`, `D1` needs to remains with the old value.

If I do fill `D1` with `=C1`, whenever `C1` change, `D1` follows.

How can I avoid `D1` to stay with old value?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot freeze the value of a cell referenced to another cell. The only way you can do it is by using *Copy* and *Paste values only* on `D1`.

**Keyboard shortcuts:**

- To copy the cells – <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>
- To paste as values – <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + V</kbd>

**or in Sheets,**

Right click `D1`, select *Copy*, right click again to `D1` and in *Paste Special*, select *Paste values only*.